# direct to and simulate web user to fill in search data(Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, watir

Currently I'm developing a flight ticket search engine(pretty similar to this-http://www.momondo.com/) which will gather all the information of a site. I' m done with the grab the info from the website.

So for each, search result,it do consist of a button like the site (Select) which will let user to redirect to according site to book the ticket.

Scenario:
on my site, I search for a location(from-to) ,then it comes out with lists of search result. I found out a search result that suit me and I click the 'Book' button and it should be redirect to AirAsia flight ticket with the data filled(like location from-to) on the Airasia site,then can direct book from the AirAsia site.

As I know for ruby on rails, there is a watir gem to simulate the user. But how to achieve this tasks? I do know when direct to the specific site , it need to pass all the parameters to the site in order to simulate or perform searching on the site.

any advice are appreaciated :D It's RoR project.

Comment: use capybara: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You do not know how to use watir gem from rails app?

Comment: can say so, and I need advice which normally what approaches will use  to achieve this.

Comment: @apneadiving normally,capybara is used for testing purpose? can it be use to perform my tasks?

Comment: yes, it could be connected to any page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the remote website in an iframe on the page and then use JavaScript to fill in the required fields.

AFAIK there isn't an easy way to fill in the fields on a remote site without using server side code on the remote site.

Comment: load a html5 iframe on my site ,and use javascript to fill the required fields into the iframe? do you know any tutorials/resources about this ?

Comment: Not off the top of my head I'm afraid. However, what you're trying to do probably isn't the best method of doing it as you are adding a lot of coupling between your site and the other site; so you might spending a lot of time keeping your application up to date. 

The way the other websites do it is by passing parameters in the URL which the remote site uses to autofill fields. Why don't you look into that instead as it is a cleaner and easier approach?

Comment: yupz, i agree with that, first thing come to my mind,actually is passing parameter in the URL which the remote site uses to autofill fields. However, my search result consists of different flight website (such as AirAsia ,Mas and etc). If passing parameter,is it there will be a different to pass different parameter to different remote site.